# wp localization: not looking into po file

Tags: wordpress, localization

I have working with clients wordpress page. It was developed in english, but now need to changed in german.

For example, I am interested in one particular translation for one particular term.
I have set up config file and it changes default language to de_DE, but nothing happends.
There are:

1) wp-content/languages/de_De.mo file
I do not know what is insided it, shoudl I care?

2) wp-content/themes/framework/localization/german/de_DE.po
This file contains the translation I need.
For example:

```
#@ default
msgid "Order Number"
msgstr "Order Number2"
```

So, I think that this should take "Order Number" and change it to "Order Number2", right?
I wonder, why po file is inside "german" folder? Is it recognized in such a way?
How to check if this file is beeing really loaded?

Btw, I have tried this file to move also to one level above:

wp-content/themes/framework/localization/de_DE.po

nothing changed.

3) wp-content/themes/framework/library/functions/general-functions.php
This file loads term I need to translate.
For example:

```
__('Order Number')
```

But wordpress doesn't look into my *.po translation. It should output 'Order number2', but it outputs 'Order number'.

I have checked that language is set to de-DE ( I have checked it using get_bloginfo('language') option just before echo-ing term I need).

Answer (score 0):

**1) `wp-content/languages/de_De.mo`**
This file contains (mostly) the translations for all the core files inside `example.com/wp-includes/`. And there should be another file, `admin-de_DE.mo`, which contains the strings for `example.com/wp-admin/`.

These translations are activated for the backend interface when you have **`define('WPLANG', 'de_DE');`** declared in the file `example.com/wp-config.php`.

**2) `wp-content/themes/framework/localization/german/de_DE.po`**
This one is the theme translation (for the frontend of the site, `example.com` ).
And here comes the *gotcha*:
**`.po`** files are master files for translating the strings, and **`.mo`** are binary files that are **actually read** by WordPress. So, when a `.po` is modified, you have to generate a new `.mo` based on it.

You need the software [PoEdit](http://www.poedit.net/screenshots.php) to open and edit `po` files, and when saving the changes the app will automatically render a new `.mo` file.

The `.mo` are the only ones you have to upload to the server. Keep a backup of you master `.po` files in a safe place, because if you update the theme you lose you master.

Check this Q&A for more details: [**How to translate a plugin via .po .mo?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57219/12615)